# How does Robert Nozick explain the Gettier problem?

Tags: logic, epistemology, knowledge, nozick, gettier

Nozick agrees that the Gettier counterexamples to the JTB analysis of knowledge are cases where someone has a JTB but does not know. What is his explanation of what has gone wrong in those cases? Specifically what conditions in Nozick’s account of knowledge are not satisfied?

Comment: Is it his counterfactual statements?

Comment: What does JTB mean?

Comment: JTB = "Justifed True Belief"

Answer (score 2):

Yes I believe it is his counterfactual statements.

One’s *true belief that p* is knowledge if and only if the following two conditions hold:

- if p were not the case, one would not believe that p,
- and if p were the case, one would believe that p.

I've only just started to research it myself, but this might help:
http://www.iep.utm.edu/epis-clo/#SH3b